# Is it possible to create installation media (iso) of Windows from existing installation

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-installation, installation-media

I have ISO of registered Windows 8 Professional. It is an old one. So when I install Windows from scratch I have to update it. Updates are quite large (at least for me with slow internet connection). I want to avoid downloading updates every time I re-install Windows. So once I have updated the fresh install is there a way that I can create an installation media (ISO) from this updated fresh install?

One other thing! I am also thinking about upgrading this install to 8.1 and then to 10. So I am thinking about creating an ISO when it is updated to 8.1 and one ISO when it is updated to 10 too.

So, is it possible? And if yes then how?

Comment: What you want is disk image software, there are many free ones, [Macrium Reflect is pretty good and they have a free version.](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) Be sure to make the bootable rescue media after installing the program.

Comment: I have uaed disk imaging tools Ghost and DriveXML to be specific. But I was thinking about a proper installation ISO with proper installation setup just like an original Windows installation whick asks for Key, language, time and other settings like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add updates to a custom ISO file: it is called "slipstreaming". There are a number of tools to help you do this, for instance WinReducer 8. There is a good guide to using this at [LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-slipstream-windows-updates-into-your-installatio-1562956432).

You will need to start all over again with Windows 10 as this is a fresh install with a different ISO. I doubt that there are slipstreaming tools for Windows 10 just yet, but as Moab notes you may actually want to look at disk image solutions.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the exact term "slipstreaming"! I can do R&D myself now! Although the guide mentioned seems to be what I would go with! As I have found on Microsoft forums that it is not possible to create install media from an already installed windows. So I think only option is to add updates in existing ISO.